# Объединение нескольких строк в одну

Tags: sed

Задача: есть файл с параметрами следующего формата:

```
ServerParam1 = [
[["a=1"],[]],
[[b=2],[]]
]
ServerParam2 = [
[["c=3"],[]],
[[d=4],[]]
]
```

Необходимо вывести **значение** параметра (то что после "=") в **одну строку**. Т.е. вывод должен быть таким:

```
ServerParam1 = [[["a=1"],[]],[[b=2],[]]]
ServerParam2 = [[["c=3"],[]],[[d=4],[]]]
```

Comment: с помощью программы *bash* это, конечно, возможно, но довольно громоздко. воспользуйтесь лучше программой, более подходящей для работы со строками. например, программой *sed*.

Comment: я уже перепробовал много вариантов с использованием sed. Может быть у вас есть вариант решения ?

Comment: ну, например: `$ sed '1~4{N;N;N;s/\n//g}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать `sed` разрешается, то можно использовать
следующий скрипт:

```sh
sed -e '/^ServerParam/ { :l; N; /\n\]$/ { s/\n//g; b; }; s/\n//g; bl; }' ./file.txt
```

Объяснение:

- При нахождении строки, начинающейся с `ServerParam`:

  - Устанавливаем метку `l`.
  - Соединяем с предыдущей строкой (`N`).
  - Если в предыдущей строке была только закрывающая скобка:

    - Убираем лишний перевод строки.
    - Выходим из цикла (`b` без аргумента).
  - Иначе:

    - Убираем лишний перевод строки.
    - Переходим на следующую итерацию по метке `l` (`bl`).

Comment: Ainar-G, большое спасибо! все работает как надо :)

Answer (score 1):

sed в таких задачах плох по причине отсутствия счётчиков, так как для универсальности такие вещи желательно решать путем подсчёта всех закрытых [ ]. Потому лучше, конечно, awk, но и на bash не сложно

```
declare -i open # [
out=
while read -d ']' l; do
        o=${l//[^[]/}
        open+=${#o}-1
        out+=${l//$'\n'/}]
        [[ open -eq 0 ]] && { printf "%s\n" "$out"; out=; }
done
```